# Use lambda to group an object within a list according to the Id of the list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Good night, I needed some help to group a list of objects using Java 8 (lambda)

I have my entity QuestionEventDTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QuestionEventDTO {
    
    public Long id;
    public QuestionDTO question;
    public List<QuestionDTO> questions;

}
```

And when I consult the bank, I get this outgoing response:

```
QuestionEventDTO [id=1, question= QuestionDTO [id=1, description="Are you Dev"], questions =[]]
QuestionEventDTO [id=1, question= QuestionDTO [id=2, description="What's rating?"], questions = []]
QuestionEventDTO [id=2, question= QuestionDTO [id=3, description="What's your dog's name?"], questions = []]
QuestionEventDTO [id=2, questao= QuestionDTO [id=4, description="Are you Dev?"], questions = []]
```

However, note that the EventQuestion_id are repeated, and only the object QuestionDto has different id's. I would like to group the QuestionsDto in a one QuestionEvent, looking like this:

```
QuestionEventDTO [id=1, question= null, questions =[ QuestaoDTO [id=1, description="Are you Dev"], QuestaoDTO [id=2, description="What's rating?"] ] ]
QuestionEventDTO [id=2, question= null, questions =[ QuestaoDTO [id=3, description="What's your dog's name?"], QuestaoDTO [id=4, description="Are you Dev?"] ] ]
```

Could someone help me in a good solution using lambda? That it is fast and efficient? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add annotation like this
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"question", "questions"})

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best way, but I'm sharing the results you want.

```
allList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(QuestionEventDTO::getId))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> {
                QuestionEventDTO newInstance = new QuestionEventDTO();
                newInstance.setId(e.getKey());
                newInstance.setQuestions(e.getValue().stream().map(v -> v.getQuestion()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                return newInstance;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `QuestionEventDTO` need to be remapped into new instances with `question` field set to `null`, and populating the list.

This may be implemented using [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) with the merge function (and `Supplier<Map>` to provide `LinkedHashMap` and keep insertion order):

```java
List<QuestionEventDto> questionEvents; // input list
List<QuestionEventDto> groupedById = new ArrayList<>(questionEvents
    .stream() // Stream<QuestionEventDto>
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        QuestionEventDto::getId, // key
        qe -> new QuestionEventDto(
            qe.getId(), null, new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(qe.getQuestion()))
        ), // use all-args constructor
        (qe1, qe2) -> { 
            qe1.getQuestions().addAll(qe2.getQuestions()); 
            return qe1;
        },
        LinkedHashMap::new // keep insertion order
    )) // Map<Long, QuestionEventDto> created
    .values() // Collection<QuestionEventDto>
); // convert to ArrayList<QuestionEventDto>
```

---

Another solution could be using `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.mapping`:

```java
List<QuestionEventDto> questionEvents; // input list
List<QuestionEventDto> groupedById = questionEvents
    .stream() 
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        QuestionEventDto::getId, // key
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(
            QuestionEventDto::getQuestion, Collectors.toList()
        ) // value - List<QuestionDto>
    ))
    .entrySet()
    .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<Long, List<QuestionDto>>>
    .map(e -> new QuestionEventDto(e.getKey(), null, e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```